# How to exit sh program?

Tags: shell, command-line

I bungled the commands and wrote `sh -man`

Now I've entered a program called `sh-3.2` that is seemingly impossible to exit.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>does not work.

`exit`, `quit`, <kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> also does not work.

All google answers are for exiting shell scripts programmatically.

Comment: Title improvements welcome; I do not know if "sh program" is the correct term.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Ctrl`+`D` does the trick for me.

Actually it is the `-n` flag that introduces this behaviour. It is meant to do only syntax checking of the commands, but doesn't actually execute them.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ctrl+d` that should kill the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>. This solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you shell exit is pre planned then use,

```
exit
```

Or you can program to handle SIGTERM  and other signals
[a sample tutorial](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php)

Or if you want to stop already running shell script

```
ctrl+c
ctrl+d
ctrl+z
```

Or find the pid and kill it.

```
ps -ax | grep shell_name
pkill -9 PID_of_shell
```

Comment: OP specifically stated that Ctrl-c,Ctrl-z, Ctrl-x and exit did not work.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Try also typing `` ` `` which is in the same key as `~` on the keyboard, and then press <kbd>Return</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> kills the terminal but `` ` `` won't.